# How can I get data from other table?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display data from another table. This is CodeIgniter framework.

I have tried many codes but they do not work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
foreach ($users->result_array() as $key => $user): ?>
   <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $key+1; ?></td>
      
      <td>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->user_model->get_user_image_url($user['id']);?>" alt="" height="50" width="50" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
      </td>

      <td> <?php echo $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name']; ?>
        <?php if($user['status'] != 1): ?>
          <small><p><?php echo get_phrase('status'); ?>: <span class="badge badge-danger-lighten"><?php echo get_phrase('unverified'); ?></span></p></small>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </td>

      <td>
        <?php echo $user['email']; ?>
      </td>

      <td>
        <?php echo $user['classcategory_id']; ?>
      </td>

      <td>
        <?php $enrolled_courses = $this->crud_model->enrol_history_by_user_id($user['id']);?>
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ($enrolled_courses->result_array() as $enrolled_course):
            $course_details = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($enrolled_course['course_id'])->row_array();?>
              <li><?php echo $course_details['title']; ?></li>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
     </td>
```

How can I change this

```
 <td>
   <?php echo $user['classcategory_id']; ?>
 </td>
```

To data from a table name "classcategory" field "name"

My controller, for user and course

```
public function get_courses() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != true) {
            redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
        }
...
$data = array();
        if(!empty($courses)) {
            foreach ($courses as $key => $row) {
                $instructor_details = $this->user_model->get_all_user($row->user_id)->row_array();
                $category_details = $this->crud_model->get_category_details_by_id($row->sub_category_id)->row_array();
                
                $sections = $this->crud_model->get_section('course', $row->id);
                $lessons = $this->crud_model->get_lessons('course', $row->id);
                $enroll_history = $this->crud_model->enrol_history($row->id);
...

public function users($param1 = "", $param2 = "") {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != true) {
            redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
        }
        if ($param1 == "add") {
            $this->user_model->add_user();
            redirect(site_url('admin/users'), 'refresh');
        }
        elseif ($param1 == "edit") {
            $this->user_model->edit_user($param2);
            redirect(site_url('admin/users'), 'refresh');
        }
        elseif ($param1 == "delete") {
            $this->user_model->delete_user($param2);
            redirect(site_url('admin/users'), 'refresh');
        }

        $page_data['page_name'] = 'users';
        $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('student');
        $page_data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_user($param2);
        $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
    }
```

My models for course and enrolled course

```
public function get_course_by_id($course_id = "")
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('course', array('id' => $course_id));
    }

public function enrol_history_by_user_id($user_id = "")
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('user_id' => $user_id));
    }
```

and my database is like this
table -> CLASSCATEGORY : column : ID + name
table -> USER : column: ID + classcategory_id

Comment: Please share your related controller and model code, the data you want and the data you get from your query. Also, provide the schema of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN USER table in your model with CLASSCATEGORY and SELECT CLASSCATEGORY.name AS categoryname, then `echo $user['categoryname']`. Here is an example of how you can join two tables in CodeIgniter

```
    $this->db->select('USER.*, CLASSCATEGORY.name AS categoryname')
         ->from('users')
         ->join('CLASSCATEGORY', 'CLASSCATEGORY.id = USER.classcategory_id')
         ->get()
         ->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getallRecords($id,$product_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $this->db->where('show', 'no');
        $this->db->where('Results !=', '0');
        $this->db->order_by('added', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit(30);
        $getallRecords=$this->db->get();
        $resultllRecords=$getallRecords->result();
        return $resultllRecords;
    }
```